# Are the people in 'Everyone' and 'Everybody' sentences referred to using singular or plural grammar?

Tags: grammatical-number

I looked through some past queries and I believe this particular take on the question has not yet been addressed:

Which of the following sentences is correct?:

Everyone was working as a volunteer.
Everyone was working as volunteers.

Should the 'volunteers' be referred to as singular or plural and why?
I personally imagine 'a volunteer' as being one giant volunteer made up of multiple people and 'volunteers' as being each separate volunteer in the group.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everyone was working as a volunteer.  (consistently singular). All were working as volunteers.  (consistently plural)

Comment: 'Everyone' means literally 'every one (person)', so each of them was _a_ volunteer.

Comment: I've just been looking for more examples from the net and have found:

Comment: How do we treat everyone as individuals?
(https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-treat-everyone-as-individuals)

Is this just incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: How do we treat everyone as an individual?  (or)  How do we treat all as individuals?